# Verifying $\frac{1-z}{z-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-1)^{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

$$z\in\mathbb{C}$$
$$\frac{1-z}{z-2}=\frac{z-1}{2-z}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{z-1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=\frac{z-1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{z}{2})^n.$$

Thus a radius of convergence of 2, but this only brings $\frac{z}{2}$ into the summation (at least I think) and I don't know how to reconcile this with the desired equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observing that the expression in the sum is involves $(z-1)$, we work by creating exactly that. Specifically :

$$\frac{1-z}{z-2}=  - \frac{z-1}{z-1-1} = \frac{z-1}{1-(z-1)} = (z-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z-1)^n = \boxed{\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-1)^{n+1}} $$

This is satisfied for $|z-1| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest way to see it is by writing $$\frac{1-z}{z-2}=\frac{(z-1)}{1-(z-1)}=(z-1)\frac1{1-(z-1)}$$and then use the fact that this is the sum of a geometric series.